# Convert three.js scene rotation to polar coordinates?

Tags: math, three.js, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

Given a three.js scene, how does one calculate the `theta` and `phi` polar coordinates from the x, y and z `position` and `rotation` property values of a `THREE.PerspectiveCamera`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to take your `x`, `y`, and `z` coordinates and plug them into the following equations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system